# Value stored to 'beaconsData' during its initialization is never read

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I get the "Value stored to 'beaconsData' during its initialization is never read" message for the marked lines and i do not quite understand why this is happening.

```
- (void)locationManager:(KTKLocationManager *)locationManager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons
{
    //NSLog(@"Ranged beacons count: %lu", [beacons count]);
    _beaconKontaktArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (CLBeacon *beacon in beacons) {
        NSDictionary *beaconsData = [[NSDictionary alloc] init]; //problem is there
        KTKBeacon *beaconData = [self _getDataForBeacon:beacon];
        if (beaconData)
        {
            beaconsData = @{@"beacon": beacon, @"ktkBeacon": beaconData};

            [_beaconKontaktArr addObject:beaconsData];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to alloc,init beaconsData here as you are already doing with @{} in the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add an object to beaconsData during definition of the variable that is never used, as you then overwrite the empty dictionary with new data in the if loop. The variable should be move to inside the loop.

```
- (void)locationManager:(KTKLocationManager *)locationManager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons {
    _beaconKontaktArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (CLBeacon *beacon in beacons) {
        KTKBeacon *beaconData = [self _getDataForBeacon:beacon];
        if (beaconData) {
            NSDictionary *beaconsData = @{@"beacon": beacon, @"ktkBeacon": beaconData};
            [_beaconKontaktArr addObject:beaconsData];
        }
    }
}
```